# EnumDisplayDevices - passing null causes error

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, null-string

The MSDN documentation for EnumDisplayDevices states that passing NULL as the first parameter to the function returns information about the display adaptor(s) on the machine (passing a string returns information about the device with that name).

Various C# examples that I have seen on-line pass null to the function as follows:

```
result = EnumDisplayDevices(null, devNum, ref dd, flags);
```

However, when I pass null as the first parameter, I get a System.AccessViolationException with the message "Attempted to read or write protected memory".

If I change null to any random non-null string (eg, "hello"), then the function call succeeds (I just don't get any device information because there isn't a device called "hello").

So how do I pass null as the first parameter to the EnumDisplayDevices function? (I need to be able to pass names in subsequent calls to the function)

Relevant snippets of my code follow:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool EnumDisplayDevices(
        string lpDevice,
        uint iDevNum,
        ref DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice,
        uint dwFlags
        );

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE
    {
        public int cb;
        public string DeviceName;
        public string DeviceString;
        public int StateFlags;
        public string DeviceID;
        public string DeviceKey;
    }

    #region Public Interface
    public ObservableCollection<DisplayDevice> LoadDisplayDevices()
    {
        ObservableCollection<DisplayDevice> displayDevices = new ObservableCollection<DisplayDevice>();

        uint devNum = 0;
        uint flags = 0;
        bool result = false;

        DISPLAY_DEVICE dd = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
        dd.cb = (int)Marshal.SizeOf(dd);

        try
        {
            result = EnumDisplayDevices(null, devNum, ref dd, flags);

            ...
```

Comment: Possibly the error is not caused by passing `null`. Possibly it's due to one of the other parameters.

Comment: I think your problem is using string instead of char[]. check out http://www.gadgetweb.de/programming/38-cs-and-the-char-mess.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original definition from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
typedef struct _DISPLAY_DEVICE {
  DWORD cb;
  TCHAR DeviceName[32];
  TCHAR DeviceString[128];
  DWORD StateFlags;
  TCHAR DeviceID[128];
  TCHAR DeviceKey[128];
} DISPLAY_DEVICE, *PDISPLAY_DEVICE;
```

All string fields are defined as fixed-size arrays. Your `DISPLAY_DEVICE` structure definition contains multiple `string` values without instructions how to marshal them, so they will be passed as pointers. You'll need to use `MarshalAsAttribute` to fix this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE
{
    public int cb;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string DeviceName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string DeviceString;
    public int StateFlags;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string DeviceID;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string DeviceKey;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, fantastic!  Your answer makes so much sense that I'm somewhat embarrassed that I hadn't thought of that.  Very much appreciated.